# GDB message "not yet allocated storage for thread-local variables"

Tags: multithreading, gdb, x86-64, nasm, thread-local-storage

Debugging a NASM shared object with gdb, I get a segmentation fault when a thread accesses its thread-local variable.  When I print the value of the thread-local variable with gdb, it responds:

```
(gdb) p MQ_FDes_Core
The inferior has not yet allocated storage for thread-local variables in the shared library `/opt/ThTest/TLS_Test.so' for Thread 0x7fffeaf26700 (LWP 4317).
```

where MQ_FDes_Core is the thread local variable.  If I execute the line "mov [MQ_FDes_Core],rax" gdb generates a segmentation fault because the tls has not yet been initialized.

The code section where this occurs is:

```
lea rdi,[MQ_Name]
mov rsi,rax
call mq_open wrt ..plt
mov [MQ_FDes_Core],rax
```

The disassembly of that section (using Agner Fog's objconv):

```
Open_message_queue:
        lea     rdi, [rel MQ_Name]                      ; 1367 _ 48: 8D. 3D, 0020230A(rel)
        mov     rsi, rax                                ; 136E _ 48: 89. C6
        call    ?_014                                   ; 1371 _ E8, FFFFFB9A(rel)
        mov     qword [rel MQ_FDes_Core], rax           ; 1376 _ 48: 89. 05, 002017E3(rel)
```

The tdata is allocated in the .tdata section:

```
section .tdata align=16
MQ_FDes_Core: dq 0
```

The NASM 2.13.02 manual section "7.9.4 Thread Local Storage in ELF: elf Special Symbols and WRT" says to write it like this for ELF64:

```
mov rax,[rel MQ_FDes_Core wrt ..gottpoff]
mov rcx,[fs:rax]
```

But with that the NASM assembler says, "error: parser: expecting ]" at the first line.

I link with ld against -ldl, -lpthread and -lrt.

I've researched a number of web resources including Ulrich Drepper's "ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage" but I don't yet know how to correct this.  Much of it focuses on C or C++ but this is NASM.

Thanks for any ideas on initializing thread local storage in a dynamically loaded shared object.

UPDATE -- A MINIMAL EXAMPLE shared object (build into a PIE executable):

```
default rel

section .tdata align=16
MQ_FDes_Core: dq 0

section .text

global main
main:
    mov qword [MQ_FDes_Core], 87
    ret
```

Build with  `nasm -f elf64 tls.asm && gcc -pie tls.o`

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1120
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555120 in main ()
(gdb) p MQ_FDes_Core 
Cannot find thread-local storage for process 642417, executable file /tmp/a.out:
Cannot find thread-local variables on this target
```

Comment: What exact command line do you use for `ld` to build the shared object?  And to link it to whatever test program is calling these functions?  Are you sure you don't need a `fs:` segment override to access thread-local storage via `mov [MQ_FDes_Core],rax`?  The machine code needs *something* to make sure different threads executing the same machine code instruction store to different addresses.

Comment: The linker string is:  ld -shared TLS_Test.o Create_Threads_in_C_Final_Core.o -ldl -lpthread -lrt -o TLS_Test.so.  I'm not sure I don't need a fs: segment override, but that seems to be the thrust of the code in the NASM manual.  That's where I am now but I don't yet know how to do it.

Comment: edit more complete details into your question.  cmon dude, you've been on Stack Overflow for a while now, you better than to leave details only in comments, right?  Also, do you have an [mcve] I could copy/paste to try on my desktop?

Comment: MRE left out because I've read a dozen SO posts on this issue, none with MREs.  It will help here so I'll post one in a few minutes.  This is a very big NASM program so it will take a few minutes.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Note that a PIE executable is a shared object, so a `main` with a `section .tid` should be sufficient to get TLS working or not.  I didn't have any luck naively trying a few things with `nasm -f elf64 tls.asm && gcc -no-pie tls.o`, including that `..gottpoff` [example from the manual](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.4).  So IDK if it's outdated or wrong.  But I get "unable to find a suitable global symbol for this reference" rather than a syntax error about the `]`

Comment: I posted a very minimal example that throws the same error (as written).  The entry point is Main_Entry_fn.  I haven't heard of a section .tid.  It looks like I need some segment override but I don't know the syntax yet.

Comment: Ok that's a good start, but it doesn't look nearly as minimal as it could be.  What's with all the push/pop and separate function? BITS 64 should be left implicit; you need `-felf64` anyway so it can only hurt. Also `mov qword [MQ_FDes_Core], 87` would save an instruction.  And why does `TLS_Test_fn` need to be `global`, let alone exist?  Also, it won't link into an executable with gcc because there's no `main`.  Is it supposed to be used with `ld -e Main_Entry_fn`?  But that wouldn't make sense because it ends with `ret`?  Does the problem you're having not occur with a PIE, only a share lib?

Comment: My reading shows that shared objects are different than executables (e.g. Ulrich Drepper), so I can make it into an exe and see if it's the same error.  That will get me part way there, but I'm still left with the problem of how to handle an .so.  The push/pop instructions are something I do on entry to every .so.  Just went quickly to get a serviceable mre.

Comment: I can understand pushing RBX and RBP if your function wants call-preserved registers, but RDI is call-clobbered.  It makes no sense to save / restore the first arg-passing register unless you're using some weird calling convention where the caller assumes that arg isn't modified.  Anyway, yes, shared libs are different in some ways, but getting something that works in `main` would obviously be a good start, and is easier to test.  Your example isn't complete if it's *just* a shared lib with no caller, so I fixed that for you.

Comment: Although my GDB error message for a PIE is different from what you got, so maybe there's a significant difference.  Still your "MCVE" was over 4x as large as it needed to be; my source could be a library just by changing `main` to any other name without adding any more lines.